# Python Tkinter Tk Calendar get custom date not working and unable to display date in format: "DD-MM-YYYY"

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, user-interface, tkinter, tkcalendar

I wanted to create a date-picker but it does not work at all, instead, irrespective of the date i pick on the following menu:

[image: The Calendar I made]

It just outputs the current date:

[image: The Output it gives every time is the current date]

The second I click on the button that is calling the function `dispcal()`, the IDLE prints out the current date automatically, I don't know why. And when I click on the button *Get This Date*, and it calls the function `getCustomDate()`, it just doesn't do what it's supposed to do, and does not print anything.

Here is the code of the date picker and calendar function:

```
def getCustomDate():
    print(cal.get_date())
def dispcal():
    global cal
    calFrame=LabelFrame(mainL,borderwidth=0, bg="#c3dde6", height=100, width=100)
    calFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
    cal=Calendar(calFrame, selectmode="day",firstweekday="monday",background="#0f8bff",foreground="black",disabledforeground="#a3bec7",bordercolor="grey",normalbackground="#d0f4ff",weekendbackground="#8ffeff",weekendforeground ="black" ,disabledbackground="99b3bc",year=int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y")),month=int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m")), day=int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d")))
    cal.pack(pady=10)
    getdat=Button(calFrame,text="Get This Date",bg="#00ffde", command=getCustomDate())
    getdat.pack()
```

### Updates

Thanks to @j_4321 for solving my problem, I created a fresh python file and ran the code in that, the one with the custom format I want for my Calendar Date Picker and it works like a charm and gives the desired output.

**fresh.py**:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import *
root=Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
def mainF():
    global cal
    def getDate():
        date=cal.get_date()
        print(date)
    cal.pack(pady=20, padx=20)
    butt=Button(root,text="Date Getter", bg="cyan",command=getDate).pack()
cal=Calendar(root,selectmode="day",date_pattern="dd-mm-y")
but=Button(root,text="Pick Date",command=mainF).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

[image: Code working Properly]

However in my **main.py**, the same code just does not work and gives the following error message:

```
<bound method Calendar.get_date of <tkcalendar.calendar_.Calendar object .!labelframe.!frame2.!frame.!frame2.!calendar>>
```

I don't know why this is happening, maybe there is a problem in my **main.py** code but I just can't seem to find it out.

Here is my **main.py** code:

```
from calendar import firstweekday
import csv, datetime
from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
now=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")

f=open("Dr Nikhil Prescription App\Patient_Data.csv","r", newline="")
reader=csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
L=[k[0] for k in reader]
try:
    sndat=str(1+(int(L[-1])))
except ValueError:
    sndat=1
f.close()

from tkinter import messagebox
def DataAdder2CSV():
    global edate, eSNO, eage, egender, ename, ePID, econtact, ecomp, eallergy, ehistory, eR
    e=edate.get()
    a=eSNO.get()
    d=eage.get()
    f=egender.get()
    b=ename.get()
    c=ePID.get()
    g=econtact.get()
    h=ecomp.get(1.0,END)
    i=eallergy.get(1.0,END)
    j=ehistory.get(1.0,END)
    k=eR.get(1.0,END)
    data=[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k]
        
    file=open("Patient_Data.csv","a", newline="")
    writer=csv.writer(file, delimiter=",")

    writer.writerow(data)

    file.close()
    messagebox.showinfo("Prescription Generator", "Data has been saved to the database successfully!")    
def PrescGen():
    from tkinter import filedialog
    root.filename=filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir="Documents", title="Choose Destination Folder")
    '''
    import win32com.client, os
    psApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Photoshop.Application")
    psApp.Open("Presc_Template.psd")
    doc = psApp.Application.ActiveDocument
    layer_facts = doc.ArtLayers["GLAYER"]
    text_of_layer = layer_facts.TextItem
    text_of_layer.contents = "This is an example of a new text."
    '''
    messagebox.showinfo("Prescription Generator", "Prescription has been saved in the desired location successfully!")  
def dispcal():

    calFrame.grid(row=1, column=0,pady=60, sticky=NSEW)
    cal.pack(pady=10,padx=50, fill="both", expand=True)

    def getCustomDate():
        print(cal.get_date)
    getdat=Button(calFrame,text="Get This Date",bg="#00ffde", command=getCustomDate)
    getdat.pack()

root=Tk()
root.config(bg="#add8e6")

megaF=LabelFrame(root,bg="#add8e6", borderwidth=0)
megaF.pack()

greet=Label(megaF,font="Arial 25",text="Prescription Generator", bg="#add8e6", fg="black").pack(pady=20)

dateF=Frame(megaF, padx=10, pady=10, bg="#c3dde6")
dateF.pack()

mega2F=Frame(megaF,bg="#c3dde6")
mega2F.pack()

date=Label(dateF,font="Arial 12",text="Date:", bg="#c3dde6").grid(row=0,column=0)

edate=Entry(dateF, width=10)
edate.insert(0,now)
edate.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5)

CalIMG=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("D:\Coding\Python Scripts\Dr Nikhil Prescription App\cal.png"))

mainL=Frame(mega2F,borderwidth=0, padx=10, pady=10, bg="#c3dde6")
mainL.grid(row=0, column=0)

calFrame=Frame(mainL,borderwidth=0, bg="#c3dde6", height=200, width=100)

cal=Calendar(calFrame,
date_pattern="dd-mm-y",
selectmode="day",
firstweekday="monday",
background="#0f8bff",
foreground="black",
disabledforeground="#a3bec7",
bordercolor="grey",
normalbackground="#d0f4ff",
weekendbackground="#8ffeff",
weekendforeground ="black" ,
disabledbackground="99b3bc")

CalButt=Button(dateF, image=CalIMG, command=dispcal, borderwidth=0, bg="#c3dde6").grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5)

main2L=LabelFrame(mega2F,borderwidth=0, padx=10, pady=10, bg="#c3dde6")
main2L.grid(row=0, column=1,pady=20, padx=40)

PDlf=Frame(mainL, padx=10, pady=13, bg="#c3dde6")
PDlf.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)

sno=Label(PDlf,font="Arial 14",text="Sno:", bg="#c3dde6").grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=E)
eSNO=Entry(PDlf, width=3)
eSNO.insert(0,sndat)
eSNO.grid(row=0, column=1)

age=Label(PDlf,font="Arial 14",text="Age:", bg="#c3dde6").grid(row=1,column=0, sticky=E)
eage=Entry(PDlf, width=3)
eage.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=10)

gender=Label(PDlf,font="Arial 14",text="Gender:", bg="#c3dde6").grid(row=2,column=0, sticky=E)
egender=Entry(PDlf, width=3)
egender.grid(row=2, column=1)

name=Label(PDlf,font="Arial 14",text="Name:", bg="#c3dde6").grid(row=0,column=3, sticky=E)
ename=Entry(PDlf, width=15)
ename.grid(row=0, column=4)

Pid=Label(PDlf,font="Arial 14",text="PatientID:", bg="#c3dde6").grid(row=1,column=3, sticky=E)
ePID=Entry(PDlf, width=15)
ePID.grid(row=1, column=4, pady=10)

contact=Label(PDlf,font="Arial 14",text="Contact:", bg="#c3dde6").grid(row=2,column=3, sticky=E)
econtact=Entry(PDlf, width=15)
econtact.grid(row=2, column=4)

blank=Label(PDlf,font="Arial 14",text="         ", bg="#c3dde6").grid(row=1,column=2)

contentLF=LabelFrame(main2L, padx=10, pady=10, bg="#c3dde6", borderwidth=0)
contentLF.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=SE)

blank=Label(PDlf,font="Arial 14",text="         ", bg="#c3dde6").grid(row=0,column=2)

complaint=Label(contentLF,font="Arial 14",text="Complaint:", bg="#c3dde6").grid(row=0,column=1, sticky=E)
ecomp=Text(contentLF, width=90, height=4)
ecomp.grid(row=0, column=2)

allergy=Label(contentLF,font="Arial 14",text="Allergy:", bg="#c3dde6").grid(row=1,column=1, sticky=E)
eallergy=Text(contentLF, width=90, height=2)
eallergy.grid(row=1, column=2, pady=10)

history=Label(contentLF,font="Arial 14",text="History:", bg="#c3dde6").grid(row=2,column=1, sticky=E)
ehistory=Text(contentLF, width=90, height=5)
ehistory.grid(row=2, column=2)

R=Label(contentLF,font="Arial 14",text="Diagnosis:", bg="#c3dde6").grid(row=3,column=1, sticky=E)
eR=Text(contentLF, width=90, height=12)
eR.grid(row=3, column=2, pady=10)

buttF=LabelFrame(main2L, bg="#c3dde6", borderwidth=0)
buttF.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=E)
genPres=Button(buttF,font="Arial 12",text="Generate Prescription", bg="#ff80b9", command=PrescGen).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, sticky=E)

csvAdd=Button(buttF,font="Arial 12",text="Add to Database", bg="#49ff9a", command=DataAdder2CSV).grid(row=0, column=1,padx=10, sticky=E)

root.title("Prescription Generator")
root.state("zoomed")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Part of your problem is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/why-is-the-command-bound-to-a-button-or-event-executed-when-declared. In `getdat=Button(calFrame,text="Get This Date",bg="#00ffde", command=getCustomDate())` you are executing the function instead of passing it as an argument.

Comment: Secondly, you are not specifying the date format you want to use, so `tkcalendar` is using the default one for your locale. Have a look at the docstring of `Calendar` (or at the online [documentation](https://tkcalendar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Calendar.html) and you will find all the info you need to do that.

Comment: But it always used to work with other things irrespective. Also, I have already been through the documentation and I used the code: `print(cal._get_date_pattern("dd-mm-yyyy"))` but it only prints out the string. "dd-mm-yyyy". How to add picture to comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, in

```
 getdat=Button(calFrame,text="Get This Date",bg="#00ffde", command=getCustomDate())
```

you are executing the function instead of passing it as an argument, like in [Why is the command bound to a Button or event executed when declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/why-is-the-command-bound-to-a-button-or-event-executed-when-declared).

Then, according to the docstring of Calendar, it takes a `date_pattern` option

> ```
> date_pattern : str
>     date pattern used to format the date as a string. The default
>     pattern used is babel's short date format in the Calendar's locale.
>
>     A valid pattern is a combination of 'y', 'm' and 'd' separated by
>     non letter characters to indicate how and in which order the
>     year, month and day should be displayed.
>
>         y: 'yy' for the last two digits of the year, any other number of 'y's for
>            the full year with an extra padding of zero if it has less
>            digits than the number of 'y's.
>         m: 'm' for the month number without padding, 'mm' for a
>            two-digit month
>         d: 'd' for the day of month number without padding, 'dd' for a
>            two-digit day
>
>     Examples for datetime.date(2019, 7, 1):
>
>         'y-mm-dd' → '2019-07-01'
>         'm/d/yy' → '7/1/19'
> ```

So just pass `date_pattern="dd-mm-yyyy"` in argument when creating the Calendar.

Here is an example

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button
from tkcalendar import Calendar

def getCustomDate():
    print(cal.get_date())

root = Tk()

cal = Calendar(root,
               selectmode="day",
               firstweekday="monday",
               background="#0f8bff",
               foreground="black",
               disabledforeground="#a3bec7",
               bordercolor="grey",
               normalbackground="#d0f4ff",
               weekendbackground="#8ffeff",
               weekendforeground ="black",
               disabledbackground="99b3bc",
               date_pattern="dd-mm-yyyy")
cal.pack(pady=10)
getdat=Button(root, text="Get This Date",
              bg="#00ffde", command=getCustomDate)
getdat.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Even I have read the documentation... sir, its not happening, the `._get_date_pattern("dd-mm-y")` just does not work whatsoever... This is what happens, I type: `print(cal._get_date_pattern("dd-mm-yyyy"))` but it only prints out the string. ```"dd-mm-yyyy"```.

Comment: I also typed that ```date_pattern="dd-mm-yyyy"``` line in the code just as you just said but it just printed out: ```dd-MM-y``` and nothing else.

Comment: Update: Now for some reason the thing is broken completely, it doesn't even print anything anymore, I don't know what has happened.

Comment: Yet another Update: It keeps printing this now: ```<bound method Calendar.get_date of <tkcalendar.calendar_.Calendar object .!labelframe.!frame2.!frame.!frame2.!calendar>>```

Comment: Can you run my whole code and see if it does what you expect? You shouldn't need to use `cal._get_date_pattern("dd-mm-yyyy")`, it's an internal method (i.e. not meant to be used), just use `.get_date()`

Comment: Yeah, I am not using ```cal._get_date_pattern("dd-mm-yyyy")``` anymore, I am using ```date_pattern="dd-mm-yyyy"``` while defining the Calendar. And yes, I made a fresh python file and your method works like a charm. It is for some reason not working at all in my ```main.py``` program that has the rest of the code. I triple checked the syntax and everything but after making the necessary changes, it just prints out: ```<bound method Calendar.get_date of <tkcalendar.calendar_.Calendar object .!labelframe.!frame2.!frame.!frame2.!calendar>>``` now and nothing else.

Comment: I am updating my question and providing screenshots...

Comment: In your `main.py` you do `print(cal.get_date)` instead of `print(cal.get_date())` so it prints the function object instead of the selected date.

Comment: holy sh*t... Such a small mistake... and literally spent the last 1 hour wondering **"HOWWW"** Thank you so much for the help sir, I really appreciate it!

Comment: I seriously cant thank you enough, **THANK YOU**