# Change date format in Tkinter date picker - python

Tags: python, tkinter, datepicker, tkcalendar

As title say, I would like to change the date format in Tkinter from m/d/y to dd/mm/yyyy

I have the following code but did not work. still the format of the date is 2/16/2022

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("700x450")


#Weekly From
cal1 = DateEntry(root, width=8, year=year, month=month, day=day,
background='darkblue', foreground='white', borderwidth=2, locale = 'en_us', date_patern ='dd.mm.yyyy')
cal1.place(x=150, y=50)

#Weekly to
cal2 = DateEntry(root, width=8, year=year, month=month, day=day,
background='darkblue', foreground='white', borderwidth=2, locale = 'en_us', date_patern ='dd.mm.yyyy')
cal2.place(x=240, y=50)
```

Comment: the potential answer could be:-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67597724/python-tkinter-tk-calendar-get-custom-date-not-working-and-unable-to-display-dat

Comment: What is `DateEntry`? That's not part of the standard tkinter package.

Comment: Typo: `date_patern` should be `date_pattern` instead.

Comment: @BryanOakley `DateEntry` is part of the `tkcalendar` module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reference:- [Python Tkinter Tk Calendar get custom date not working and unable to display date in format: "DD-MM-YYYY"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67597724/python-tkinter-tk-calendar-get-custom-date-not-working-and-unable-to-display-dat)

You could do something like this:-

```
from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import *
root=Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
def mainF():
    global cal
    def getDate():
        date=cal.get_date()
        print(date)
    cal.pack(pady=20, padx=20)
    butt=Button(root,text="Date Getter", bg="cyan",command=getDate).pack()
cal=Calendar(root,selectmode="day",date_pattern="dd-mm-y")
but=Button(root,text="Pick Date",command=mainF).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

this is a small date picker app, that changes the format to dd-mm-yy instead of mm-dd-yy, you can implement format change in your code like this

Comment: I have not tried you code, but I had a Typo in my code

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer :

```
cal = DateEntry(c12, width=30, background="green",date_pattern="yyyy-mm-dd")    
cal.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=(10, 0), ipadx=50)
```

Copy `date_pattern="yyyy-mm-dd"` and put it inside your entry